# I want apk to open the second page first

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I made the second page a menu. I want the second page to open when the apk opens. How can I do this with code? I only need a code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I cannot express myself because I do not speak English.. sorry

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file you will have something like this:

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

And you something like this for other acitivities:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity" />
```

What you need to do is just copy/paste that `<intent-filter></intent-filter>` tags to the `SecondActivity`, and you get this:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity" />
```

Comment: I couldn't do it, I'm very sorry. The name of the page I want to be the home page is KOMIKSOSLER     android:resizeableActivity = "true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: Okay, do you see in your AndroidManifset that activity named KOMIKSOSLER? Besides the MainActivity. There should be something like <activity android:name=".KOMIKSOSLER" /> ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code in AndroidManifest.xml file is like following:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
```

You just have to set the second activity as the launcher of the app, i.e copy/paste `<intent-filter>` from .MainActivity to .SecondActivity. Like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And that's it! Now the second page opens the app.